# Audio element playing twice in js for WebAudio API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-audio-api, webapi

In my reactjs project,i am trying the text to speech feature and getting audio from node backend and the problem is audio element playing twice and i am using webAudio api.

```
const audio = new Audio(
  `${process.env.REACT_APP_TTS_URL}` + encodeURI(newText)
);
audio.onended = () => {
  console.log("ended");
  setplayingTTS(false);
};
audio.play();

//this is the audio tag    
<audio
      id="audio_tts"
      preload="none"
      allow="autoplay"
      type="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm">
</audio>
```

[network tab screenshot for this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1fz.png)

Comment: can you please share the setplayingTTS function? here the audio tag seems to do nothing

Comment: @Aurangzeb I think "setplayingTTS" is only setting a boolean React State, rather than a function itself, using useState Hook.

Comment: @aurangzeb it is a react usestate hook like Varun said

Comment: then just removing audio.play() statement should do the trick, comment it out, and it should work